# Having clause with subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below scenario

```
CREATE TABLE plch_sales
(
   region      VARCHAR2 (100),
   product     VARCHAR2 (100),
   amount   NUMBER
)
/

INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('North', 'Magic Wand',  1000);
INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('North', 'Skele-Gro',   1000);
INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('North', 'Timeturner ', 1000);
INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('South', 'Portkey',     1000);
INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('South', 'Quaffle',     1000);
INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('West',  'Imperius',    1000);
INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('West',  'Gringotts',   1000);
COMMIT;
```

why the below query is producing no rows? the database is oracle.

```
select region, sum(amount) sm_amount from PLCH_SALES group by region having sum(amount) > (select sum(amount)/3 from PLCH_SALES);
```

Comment: What you want here actually?

Comment: That's a bug I'd say...

Comment: And this will return  the row `.. > (select sum(amount)/3 + 0 from PLCH_SALES)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to first do the `sum() and then divide it by 3` like the below -

```
SELECT region, SUM(amount) sm_amount
FROM PLCH_SALES
GROUP BY region
HAVING SUM(amount) > (SELECT SUM(amount)FROM PLCH_SALES)/3;
```

OR you can alternatively try using `window() aggregate function`

```
select distinct region,sm_amount from
(
select region,sum(amount) over(partition by region) as sm_amount, sum(amount) over()/3 as total
from plch_sales
)a where sm_amount>total
```

Comment: May I ask why `need to first do the sum() and then divide it by 3`? What is the cause the original query by OP not giving results?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, usually it should return result with OP's query but after checking it in all database it seems to me it is something Oracle-specific - you can check here  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5629958971bb28a89155fcda77c7f716

Comment: Yes actually I noticed another thing If we just put the same statement `(select sum(amount)/3 + 0 from PLCH_SALES)` into the select values simply it's working even with OP's query . Strange behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written will not work with having clause .

There are multiple ways to do it like with CTE , Parent_table  or like below :

```
select region, sum(amount) sm_amount 
from PLCH_SALES 
group by region 
having sum(amount) >(sum(amount)/3 )
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work.  The subquery returns:

```
2333.333333333333333333333333333333333333
```

The query without the `having` returns:

```
REGION  SM_AMOUNT
West    2000
North   3000
South   2000
```

So clearly, `'North'` should be in the result set.

However, it does not in Oracle.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=20c33f87f00cc73754f2403adeb015a1) is a db<>fiddle.  It *does* work with a subquery:

```
select x.*
from (select region, sum(amount) as sm_amount, (select sum(amount)/3 from PLCH_SALES) as thirds
      from PLCH_SALES
      group by region
     ) x
where sm_amount > thirds ;
```

And it does work with a CTE:

```
with thirds as (
      select sum(s2.amount)/3 as val from PLCH_SALES s2
     )
select region, sum(amount) sm_amount
from PLCH_SALES
group by region
having sum(amount) > (select val from thirds);
```

This sounds like a bug.

The query works in other databases:

- [Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5a977ff47d231a6e3f79d51c2524d837)
- [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5a977ff47d231a6e3f79d51c2524d837)
- [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2dd97f8e2439dc82c464a00f5d3f4783)

And no doubt any other database where one would try it.

Comment: did you check my comment on Fahmi's answer ? If we put the sub query just to select clause it's working in Oracle also? then does it mean something ? I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 . . . I don't interpret your question as "how to write the logic" (although this answers that question).  I interpret it as "why your code doesn't work".  The answer to that appears to be a bug in Oracle.  The code is fine; it works in any other database (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: No no you misunderstood me. I am not trying to answer but what I am asking you is....Does it mean something to you  ? when I put into select clause and it's working. I by myself cannot figure it out and that where needed your inputs. But anyway thanks for your reply and bottom line is this seems to be bug.